# Dynamically registering datasources in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a `database.properties` file containing all the information to create a `DataSource`.

I have written a class that is registering the `datasource` by reading that properties file.

```
Code:

@Bean(name="firstDS")
public DataSource firstDataSource()
{
    BoneCPDataSource ds = new BoneCPDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClass(driver); //get properties from db.properties file
    ds.setJdbcUrl(url);
    ds.setUsername(user);
    ds.setPassword(pass);
    return ds;
}
```

and the I'm getting `JdbcTemplate` like this

```
@Bean(name = "someDs")
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate()
{
    return new JdbcTemplate(firstDS);
}
```

What I need is that if I have multiple datasources mentioned in `database.properties` file, how can I load them all and register them to `context`.

I was thinking of creating a `Map<>` of the properties and then Iterate over it and register all those `Datasources`.

OR

Is there some convenient or `Spring` way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if I am getting your question right

.I believe you will need to set up multiple Beans for each datasource and then set one as Primary

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Hope this helps